# Merging two MySQL tables with sorted datetime

Tags: mysql, merge

Sorry if this sounds silly. Right now, I only have a basic understanding of MySQL and relational databases. Basically I can only do some simple SELECTs ;)

 As usual, I did my Google and StackOverflow research before posting this, but I couldn't find any suitable answer (the ones on SO were almost every time with "0" value).
I will try to make it as generic as possible so that it could be useful to somebody else.
Let's say I have two tables:

```
TBUY
  qtyBuy   : integer
  dateBuy  : datetime

TSELL
  qtySell  : integer
  dateSell : datetime
```

I would like to be able to write a query so that I can have a resulting table of qtyBuy/qtySell SORTED by the "merge" of the two dates, e.g. if those two tables are the "history" of some items beign bought and sold, I would like to know the history of that item, sorted by date.
I know that it's fairly easy to make the two different SELECTs and then, in whatever programming language you are using, merging the result "by hand". But I was wondering if there was a better way using MySQL.
I was thinking something like

> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbuy UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tsell) 
>   ORDER BY whichDate?!

But I do not know how to specify "whichDate". Thank you.

Comment: These tables list buy and sell information for a single product?

Comment: The date column would have the name from the first subquery.  Because you have not renamed it with a column alias, it would be `dateBuy`.

Comment: To Marcus Adams: yes, it's a single product (well, I have "filtered it" already for a single product)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
select "buy" as action, qtyBuy as item, dateBuy as actionDate 
from TBUY
union all
select "sell" as action, qtySell as item, dateSell as actionDate
from TSELL
order by actionDate
```

?

Since I can't guess what is qtyBuy, I don't know if you instead should join the tables.

As soon as you want a date-line with no wholes, you need an extra table with the dates. SQL can only read and combine values, but not create them out of nothing.

Comment: Great. Perfect. I didn't know you could "select a string constant" and name it as you liked. Thank you.

Comment: @ZioBit: I have seen Statements which use CONCAT to produce complete SQL statements as the result. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

instead of `*` use the names of the columns then you can rename the `dateBuy` and `dateSell` columns to something lets say `date`.

In the Order-part of the statement you can use the new name (`dateMerged`) to order the resultset.

```
SELECT qtyBuy as qtyChange, dateBuy as dateMerged FROM tbuy 
UNION ALL SELECT -1 * qtySell, dateSell FROM tsell
ORDER BY dateMerged
```

The resultset of UNION conains the columnnames of the first SELECT-statement, so you might use dateBuy too, but that is not a speaking name in the UNION...

Comment: I think you'll still want `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I think the subselect is useless (but it wouldn't hurt much), and giving beginners the tip to use reserved words could also be avoided...

Comment: thanks, I edited the query. But I'm not sure wether it works.

Comment: It works but - my fault - the given result doesn't let me understand if any row is referring to a "buy" or to a "sell". Is there a way I can add a column to "inform" me if that row has been generated by TSELL or TBUY?

Comment: yes there is, did you also try the answer flaschenpost wrote? he creates a coulmn with the name of the action "buy"/"sell".

Comment: A different way could be to multiply the qtySell with -1.
So when you perform a sum on qtyMerged you get the current stock.
I already changed the statement this way.

Comment: Good idea, thank you! I will use that idea to make the query even bigger :) Now it is already pretty big, since the "date" was actually a datetime, I extracted only the date part, "group-by" the date, and since in reality every row of the "sell" means "1" and I have a specific "qty" field in "buy", I used count(*) for the first calculation, and sum(qty) for the second, and everything still works (albeit I guess it will become slooooow after a while, but it is just something I am doing for myself).